# Options to add DB2 to my development environment

Tags: ssis, db2

I am planning to build a development environment for an SSIS package that extracts data from a single simple DB2 table.

I have 18 years of experience with SQL Server but haven't worked with DB2 at all.

How easy is to install a developer edition of DB2 in my development environment, create a table and read data from it?

Is there any free developer edition of DB2 available?

**Update 1**

@MichaelTiefenbacher, is DB2 Express-C's SQL language and connectivity protocol compatible with other DB2 servers? My application needs to work ultimately with a Mainframe/DB2 server. All my application needs to do is doing a SELECT query against a DB2 table. I am hoping to build and unit test my application with the DB2 Express-C. Once I am done with development, then do the final test with the Mainframe DB2 in a QA environment. Would that work? With SQL server, I usually build/test my application with a free SQL Express, and it I know it will work with all other versions of SQL server. I wonder if I can have the same convenient with DB2 as ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great starting point can be this:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/db2express/

The DB2 Express-C is free and you will find other usefule links like the DB2 documentation in IBM Knowledge Center alsready linked on above page.

Ther eis also a so called DB2 Developer Edition - but this one is not free - which will give you all additional DB2 options and products.

Thre is a SAMPLE database in DB2 which can be created with the command

> db2sampl

to get a set of tables to experiment with.
The installation process is easy you will amnage it :-)

Comment: Hi @MichaelTiefenbacher, thank you for help. Would you be able to comment on my updated question?

Comment: The SQL on the LUW platform is identical - but compared to DB2 z/OS in the host there are some differences - although most is pretty much the same. I suggest to refer to following cross-platform development information: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0206sqlref/0206sqlref.html